# How to open multiple Modern UI Google Chrome Windows?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Is it possible to somehow trick Windows 8(.1) to open multiple Google Chrome Windows on the modern UI side?

I'm using multiple profiles with Crhome and would like to see all of them at once. By default only one window is visible. In desktop mode switching profile opens up a new window. In Modern UI it replaces the existing window. If I open up incognito window, I still get just one Chrome instance.

I assume one way for doing this might be to get Windows 8 to think the different Chrome profiles are different applications, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: This seems to be possible in Windows 8.1 with Internet Explorer 11: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2043091/deep-inside-windows-8-1s-hidden-new-features.html